# Kubernetes scheduler: watch of *api.Pod ended with error: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Yesterday service worked fine. But today when i checked service's state i saw:

```
Mar 11 14:03:16 coreos-1 systemd[1]: scheduler.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Mar 11 14:03:16 coreos-1 systemd[1]: Unit scheduler.service entered failed state.
Mar 11 14:03:16 coreos-1 systemd[1]: scheduler.service failed.
Mar 11 14:03:16 coreos-1 systemd[1]: Starting Kubernetes Scheduler...
Mar 11 14:03:16 coreos-1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes Scheduler.
Mar 11 14:08:16 coreos-1 kube-scheduler[4659]: E0311 14:08:16.808349    4659 reflector.go:118] watch of *api.Service ended with error: very short watch
Mar 11 14:08:16 coreos-1 kube-scheduler[4659]: E0311 14:08:16.811434    4659 reflector.go:118] watch of *api.Pod ended with error: unexpected end of JSON input
Mar 11 14:08:16 coreos-1 kube-scheduler[4659]: E0311 14:08:16.847595    4659 reflector.go:118] watch of *api.Pod ended with error: unexpected end of JSON input
```

It's really confused 'cause etcd, flannel and apiserver work fine.

Only some strange logs are for etcd:

```
Mar 11 20:22:21 coreos-1 etcd[472]: [etcd] Mar 11 20:22:21.572 INFO      | aba44aa0670b4b2e8437c03a0286d779: warning: heartbeat time out peer="6f4934635b6b4291bf29763add9bf4c7" missed=1 backoff="2s"
Mar 11 20:22:48 coreos-1 etcd[472]: [etcd] Mar 11 20:22:48.269 INFO      | aba44aa0670b4b2e8437c03a0286d779: warning: heartbeat time out peer="6f4934635b6b4291bf29763add9bf4c7" missed=1 backoff="2s"
Mar 11 20:48:12 coreos-1 etcd[472]: [etcd] Mar 11 20:48:12.070 INFO      | aba44aa0670b4b2e8437c03a0286d779: warning: heartbeat time out peer="6f4934635b6b4291bf29763add9bf4c7" missed=1 backoff="2s"
```

So, I'm really stuck and don't know what's wrong. How can i resolve this problem? Or, how can i check details log for scheduler.
`journalctl` give me same logs like `systemd status`

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/5311

> It means apiserver accepted the watch request but then immediately terminated the connection.
>
> If you see it occasionally, it implies a transient error and is not alarming. If you see it repeatedly, it implies that apiserver (or etcd) is sick.

Is something actually not working for you?

Comment: It's not clear to me that etcd is actually broken and needs fixing. Are there symptoms beyond these log messages?

Comment: I don't understand what this logs actually mean. Cause even with this messages in logs i still can ping another nodes...

Comment: My reading of these log messages is that your network dropped a few packets but everything recovered and is working fine. It's not clear to me that there is anything you need to fix right now.